# Is it possible to use an ansible role to set a _passed_ variable value?

Tags: variables, ansible

My scenario consists of two playbooks:

- playbook P1 uses two roles A, and B,
- playbook P2 uses just the role A.

Now, the roles A and B need to perform couple of additional steps, doing the same operations, but resulting in a different variable. Example:

```
# role A
- name: get the current_path
  shell: pwd
  register: A_path_variable

# role B, in a separate file
- name: get the current_path
  shell: pwd
  register: B_path_variable
```

The operations needed are the same - but the resulting variable name is different.

Is there some in Ansible to tell a role to use a specific variable? E.g.: one could separate the "shell: pwd" to a new role, then ask it to use "specific_variable" to register the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use role parameters:

roles/util:

```
- shell: pwd
  register: util_output
```

playbook:

```
roles:
   - util
   - { role: role_a, my_variable_a: "{{util_output}}" }
   - { role: role_b, my_variable_b: "{{util_output}}" }
```

Comment: Coming back to this after some time, that is indeed the way - you can use roles with additional variables like this.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation - it turns out the variable resolving is simply string based.

Role A and B, executed in a single playbook, both invoking a role UTIL, expecting it to write to different variables. Role UTIL should process some data and write result to a variable.

Role A:

```
...
vars: 
  output_var_name: my_variable_A
roles:
   - UTIL
```

Role B:

```
...
vars: 
  output_var_name: my_variable_B
roles:
   - UTIL
```

UTIL, in the end

```
- name: output result
  set_fact: 
    "{{ output_var_name }}={{ local_variable }}"
```

Result: my_variable_B and my_variable_A are both set accordingly. My understanding is that "vars" gets executed before "roles", so it can change at the right moment, the right value.